# Nonparametric regression on data with known noise parameterization

Tags: prior, splines, nonparametric-regression, semiparametric

What's the best way to regress on data for which we don't have a parameterised generative model (e.g. an arbitrary non-smooth continuous signal, that can be regressed in model-free ways with splines, wavelets etc.), but for which we known the noise parameterization (e.g. that noise is sampled from a zero mean Gaussian distribution with known variance)? In case of parametric regression, the prior knowledge of noise can be straightforwardly introduced in MLE based learning as a regularization term, but is something similar possible in the scenario I describe above?